# Is it possible to group independent async functions under a single await?

Tags: javascript, async-await

## Background

I am writing some asynchronous code in express. In one of my end points there I need to retrieve some data from firebase for 2 seperate things.

- one posts some data
- the other retrieves some data to be used in a calculation and another post.

These 2 steps are not dependent on one another but obviously the end result that should be returned is (just a success message to verify that everything was posted correctly).

## Example code

```
    await postData(request);
    const data = await retrieveUnrelatedData(request);
    const result = calculation(data);
    await postCalculatedData(result);
```

In the code above `postData` will be holding up the other steps in the process even though the other steps (`retrieveUnrelatedData` & `postCalculatedData`) do not require the awaited result of `postData`.

## Question

Is there a more efficient way to get the `retrieveUnrelatedData` to fire before the full `postData` promise is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course! The thing you need to know is that `async`/`await` are using `Promises` as their underlying technology. Bearing that in mind, here's how you do it:

```
const myWorkload = request => Promise.all([
  postData(request),
  calculateData(request)
])

const calculateData = async request => {
  const data = await retrieveUnrelatedData(request);
  const result = calculation(data);
  return await postCalculatedData(result);
}

// Not asked for, but if you had a parent handler calling these it would look like:
const mainHandler = async (req, res) => {
  const [postStatus, calculatedData] = await myWorkload(req)
  // respond back with whatever?
}
```

Comment: edit suggestion: `const [_,data] = await retrieveUnrelatedData(request);` because `retrieveUnrelatedData` returns a promise of array but the first element of that array is never used in OPs code. So you should pass data[1] to `calculation` or deconstruct the returned array.